# How to increase no of IP addresses (Rule) to be whitelisted in Azure Cloud Service Access Control List

Tags: azure, acl, azure-cloud-services

I am using Access Control List in the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg for Azure Cloud service. However, it does not allow more than 50(Or less) IP addresses or rules under AccessControl element.

NetworkConfiguration/AccessControls/AccessControl/Rule action=...

How can add unlimited /Rule?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Service Access Control Lists, like other resources in Azure, have specific limits. In this case, 50 ACL's on a Cloud Service. There is no "unlimited" rule, aside from simply increasing the allowed IP range for your various rules. And there's no option to lift the 50-rule limit.

Note: The 50-rule limit is per *endpoint*.

Comment: How can then we allow more than 50 ACL's in Cloud Service? Is there any way?